# Swift NSXML parser errors

Tags: ios, xml, swift

I am getting compilation errors

```
var xmlUrl:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "xml")) ;



let parser:NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: xmlUrl);
```

//also

```
func getXML()->DataVO[]{
    parser.shouldProcessNamespaces=false;
    parser.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes=false;
    parser.delegate=self
    parser.parse()

}

 //multiple compilation errors below
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!,didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI namespaceURI String!, qualifiedName qualifiedName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!){

}
```

I get error below, even though xmlURL is defined one line above
/Users/kfamily/Documents/xcode_git/nitniem2/nitniem2/JapjiReader.swift:20:57: 'JapjiReader.Type' does not have a member named 'xmlUrl'

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here.  Can you copy and paste the entire file, as well as the specific compilation error?

Comment: I get error below, even though xmlURL is defined one line above
/Users/kfamily/Documents/xcode_git/nitniem2/nitniem2/JapjiReader.swift:20:57: 'JapjiReader.Type' does not have a member named 'xmlUrl'